# Why so many X11 Directories?

Tags: xorg

Under the usr/bin directory, I have 45 levels of X11 directories, which are all duplicates of each other. Can anyone explain why this is happening, and can I delete the intermediate ones, or will this break some path info somewhere?

Comment: I have that too. I have no idea why, but I do not think deleting them is a good idea.

Comment: The previous answer noted they are symbolic links, but does NOT explain what created them, or why they keep reproducing.   Also, I am not sure I agree with that previous answer.  Any way I can verify they are symbolic links?